# Hypergeom in Matlab R2007b

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and would appreciate any help with this problem.

I want to solve for a few Hypergeometric functions, but R2007b version of Matlab doesn't seem to know that there is a hypergeom function. (I will show you the simplest form of the code and the error message that I get)

(*in file Untitled2just.m*)

```
clear;
hypergeom([2, 16],[3,1],-7);

ERROR 
??? Attempt to execute SCRIPT Hypergeom as a function:
F:\INTERSNHIP at RRI\Matlab\Hypergeom.m

Error in ==> Untitled2just at 2
hypergeom([2, 16],[3,1],-7);
```

(*F:\INTERSNHIP at RRI\Matlab\Hypergeom.m* - this is another file that has hypergeom function, and saved with the name Hypergeom.m )

Is there anyway I can get hypergeom function to work on Matlab R2007b version?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The function [hypergeom](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html) is part of the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://se.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) and may not be available to you if you only have the basic R2007b.

Normally if you try to run a function that doesn't exist you get an error.

```
??? Undefined function or method 'hypergeom'
```

The error you get is due to the fact that you have a local script named *Hypergeom.m*.

So at your call

```
hypergeom([2, 16],[3,1],-7);
```

Matlab recognize that there is a script of function in your `path` that matches the name. But your local file is a [script and not a function](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html). Also see the [precedence order](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) in Matlab.

So to fix it, either check how to use your local script (perhaps it reads inputs from the workspace) or acquire the Symbolic Math toolbox.